# Spring social oauth how to get sign in provider in SocialUserDetailsService?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, spring-social

In my Spring Social app, I'm trying to integrate certain Social Login functionalities. After being redirected from, for example Twitter, Spring calls the following to look up the user.

```
public class SimpleSocialUserDetailsService implements SocialUserDetailsService {

@Override
public SocialUserDetails loadUserByUserId(String userId) throws UsernameNotFoundException,     DataAccessException {
/*
Commented
*/
}
```

However, since I will have multiple social login providers, the userId alone is not enough for me to look up the user in my database. I need at least the sign in provider or access token.

Is there anyway to get the sign in provider, or more information, in SocialUserDetailsService? Any other way to solve my problem would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Spring Social is rather Agnostic to the Sign in Providers when properly implemented. I believe you are confused on the flow of Spring Social. At the point you describe spring social has already looked up the connections table and presumably found a record, so it looks up your user table for the user matching with userId (as referenced in the connections table) This is usually associated with the username.

This connection <-> User matching is done in the SocialAuthenticationProvider before calling the SocialUserDetails loadUserByUserId method.

So the SocialAuthenticationProvider already does what you ask for by querying the usersConnectionRepository and comparing the provider connection to find the appropriate user.

Now for your case you would can go ahead and override the user service that you have setup. As long as the userId used on the doPostSignUp call matches the one you look up in the loadUserByUserId, the proper user will be retrieved.

This is a sample:

Wherever your signup logic is executed, you call the doPostSignup and pass the desired user id (Username or another uniquely identifiable String)

```
ProviderSignInUtils.doPostSignUp(variableForNewUserObject.getId().toString(), request);
```

Now you Override the loadUserByUserId in SimpleSocialUserDetailsService

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
public SocialUserDetails loadUserByUserId(String userId) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userId);

    return (SocialUserDetails) userDetails;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info! I'm still a bit confused though. When is doPostSignup to be called?

The solution I'm using, is I extend ConnectionSignUp. In String execute(Connection<?> connection), using the Connection object, I combine the twitter user id and signin provider, to create a myUserId. And then persist it to my user table.  I then return this myUserId, and I found that spring will use store that as the userId in the UserConnection table.

So the next time the user logs in, loadUserByUserId will give me myUserId, and I can easily look up my user table for their data.
Does this sound OK?

Comment: What are you using as your data source? Typically the user id would be auto generated by your datastore as the primary key as to avoid duplicates, so you wouldn't have any part in that.

Comment: doPostSignUp is part of the ProviderSignInUtils which give you some helper methods so that you don't have to deal with the connectionRepository. doPostSignup is typically called after you create a user to persist the connection relationship. It uses a connectionRepository to save it for you. The user table itself would be entirely unaware of any provider information. UserConnection table uses user id and provider id as primary keys, so you don't have to put provider logic into the user table as UserConnection table does it all for you.

Comment: Got it Bill, I'm beginning to understand thank you! One final question, I'm trying to automatically register and login the user after they click the social login button, no further registration needed. Where should I put the code that creates a new user in the 'User' table, gets the auto generated primary key(user id), and call doPostSignUp to pass the newly generated user id? In ConnectionSignUp execute()?